# Unwanted SQL Server Login Dialog Box repeatedly pops up while running Access Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, vba

While running a form that runs multiple queries that connect to an ODBC Database I get the SQL Server Login Dialog box. I can click OK to login since I am able to use a trusted connection.

Since this query is automatically run through a VBA macro that loops through multiple queries multiple times, the dialog box appears quite often. I would just click OK every time it pops up but in this case it takes a very long time to run.

Is there a way to prevent this dialog box from even showing up?

VBA Code:

```
Private Sub Run_All_Months_Click()
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rst As Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb()
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("MDate query")

With rst
.MoveFirst
[BOP Date].Value = rst("Monthly Dates").Value
.MoveNext
[Reporting Date].Value = rst("Monthly Dates").Value
DoCmd.RunMacro ("Monthly Report Macro")
Do
    [BOP Date].Value = rst("Monthly Dates").Value
    .MoveNext
    If (Not .EOF) Then
        [Reporting Date].Value = rst("Monthly Dates").Value
        DoCmd.RunMacro ("Monthly Report Macro")
    End If
Loop Until .EOF
End With
db.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: You have something in your code or some network issues or something because this is not normal. Your connection is stored in (I am assuming) your linked table and you should NOT be asked for the info ever, unless you are using SQL Auth and not saving the password.

Comment: I added the code in the question. It enters the "Monthly Report Macro" which just opens one of the queries. If I hit cancel instead of OK on the dialog box the debugger stops on the line with the Monthly Report Macro. If I clicked on the query itself the dialog box shows up so I think the code I posted is fine, and it's something in the query or as posted before a network error or something

Comment: The code you posted doesn't contain any connection to SQL Server - it must be in the Monthly Report Macro.  Can you post the code for that too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure out the problem. I had to relink all of the tables from the OBDC  by right clicking on one of them which brought up an option to relink. The VBA code was working correctly